# how to get javascript unique window name

Tags: javascript

How do I get window.name to 'stick' between refreshes?

I'm trying to use window.name to distinguish between multiple browser windows, so each one can show different kinds of data but on the same URL.

But `window.name` won't stick.

Here's my test code in the middle of the page...

```
document.write( '<br> before set is: ' + window.name ); 
window.name = "blah"; 
document.write( '<br> after set is: ' + window.name );
```

And here's the page output, which shows that it's not sticky...

```
before set is: showframe
after set is: blah
```

Comment: there are only 2 lines of output which means that there must have been a javascript exception on the line above the last `document.write`

Comment: So what's your question? Why are you concerned of the fact that you can change the name of the window?

Comment: Sorry -- I accidentally left that 3rd line in.  Page edited.

THE QUESTION:  How do I get window.name to 'stick' between refreshes?

Comment: do you allow opening various window from same .html / .php page at the same time?

Comment: Yes.
User can open two browser windows from same page, which allows viewing polled embedded data from multiple sources.

Comment: Oops party is finished... but
why dont you use `timestamp` and a long random number to differentiate it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`window.name` does stick.** Besides my own observations, this is backed by 3 sources:

- Your own code. Where is "showframe" coming from? Answer: This is the `window.name` that was set *previously* by some other page in that window. You then overwrite it and get this new value. This is the expected behavior.
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name says

  > Modern browsers will reset Window.name to an empty string if a tab loads a page from a different domain

  ...which (kinda) means that it sticks if a tab loads a page from the same domain ;-)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35596134/1668200 recommends `window.name` instead of `sessionStorage`

Final tip: Never start by reading the existing `window.name` - this might be the value from some previous page.