# SessionStorage is not empty when link opened in new tab in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, session-storage

I need to have some unique id on every opened browser tab (in a javascript object). The Id must be saved through requests and i decided to use sessionStorage for it. 
When i opens the new page in browser it works well. 
But when i click a link by right mouse button and choose 'Open link in new tab' in IE 11 - sessionStorage is not empty. So my expectations about new id failed .

Chrome works another way, sessionStorage is empty.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem for IE?

Comment: After some experiments I've found that sessionStorage in new tab has been copied from the tab I clicked.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an ancient question but I just today struggled with this myself. I was opening a new tab with a link with `target="_blank"` expecting the sessionStorage to be empty. It was not.

NOTE: All of this is untested code but you should get the jist. Also the browser I was experiencing this problem with was Firefox 44.0.2.

My code was something along these lines:

**Problematic code:**

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    //Get saved session data
    var persistedObject = null;

    try{
        persistedObject = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('tabData'));
    }catch(e){}
});

function updateSessionStorage(){
    var objectToPersist = {};

    //Get some data to persist
    objectToPersist.value1 = "some data";

    //Save the data in the session storage
    sessionStorage.setItem('tabData', JSON.stringify(objectToPersist));
}
```

This picked up data from earlier tabs that were closed.

I solved this by changing my code to something like this:

**Working code:**

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    //Get saved session data
    var persistedObject = null;

    try{
        persistedObject = JSON.parse(window.name);
    }catch(e){}
});

function updateSessionStorage(){
    var objectToPersist = {};

    //Get some data to persist
    objectToPersist.value1 = "some data";

    //Save the data in the session storage
    window.name = JSON.stringify(objectToPersist);
}
```

This worked beautifully. The window name is persisted until you close the tab/window, which is exactly what I was expecting sessionStorage to do. New pages is always loaded with `window.name = ""` if no name was given on the link handling side.

What you might miss out on is the fact that you can't straight out of the box use names such as my `sessionStorage.setItem('tabData', 'some data')` but you can easily avoid this by doing something like this:

**Suggestion:**

```
function updateSessionStorage(){
    var objectToPersist = {};

    try{
        objectToPersist = JSON.parse(window.name);
    }catch(e){}

    if(objectToPersist[tabData] == undefined){
        objectToPersist.tabData = {};
    }

    //Get some data to persist
    objectToPersist.tabData.value1 = "some data";

    //Save the data in the session storage
    window.name = JSON.stringify(objectToPersist);
}
```

I hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.

Comment: In short, the essence of this answer is: **Don't use sessionStorage** at all; use `window.name` instead.

Comment: Damn it, you're genius. Tks so much